# Any way to style a MUI Chip with the same length as another one

Tags: user-interface, material-ui, datagrid

I want to display some mui chips with different labels and they should be the same length.

e.g. it should look something like this

[image: MUI Chips same length]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out, one way to do so is by simply adding the style tag minWidth to all of them

```
<Chip
  sx={{ borderRadius: 1 }}
  variant="outlined"
  label={'Pending'}
  style={{
   backgroundColor: '#FEF8E8',
   color: '#FFBD00',
   border: 'none',
   minWidth: '100px'
   }}
/>
```